# ASP.NET UserControl javascript is not loading HTML to its variable

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net

I have created UserControl that I wish to use on multiple pages. This control contains classic javascript but for some reason it will not load element to a variable. Client IDs look ok.

This is button that activates javascript:

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContactList$btn_NewContact" value="Potvrdit" onclick="javascript:return CheckContactName();" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContactList_btn_NewContact" class="MyButton" style="color:white;" />
```

This is the textbox:

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ContactList$con_fullname" type="text" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_ContactList_con_fullname" class="MyTextBox" />
```

This is Javascript function:

```
    function CheckContactName() {
    name = document.getElementById("ContentPlaceHolder1_ContactList_con_fullname");

    if (name.value == '' | name.value == null) {
        return false;
    }

    UploadContact();

    return true;
}
```

Now, when I debug this in a console the **name.value** is undefined. The **name** variable itself is just **"[object HTMLInputElement]"**.

So no matter what is in that textbox, this function is always false. I also checked all IDs inside final client page and there are no duplicates. Can you tell why this is? Thanks.

Comment: try set your input type to button not submit. As submit in webforms application will do a postback, so this could be the issue of your problem.

Comment: Problem with that is that in my .aspx file I use button like this:
<asp:Button ID="btn_NewContact" runat="server" Text="Potvrdit" CssClass="MyButton" style="color:white;" OnClientClick="javascript:return CheckContactName();" OnClick="btn_NewContact_Click"/> 
OnClientClick return false it should not do postback

Comment: ok... have you enabled viewstate on control. page or global on the project.

Comment: no, should I do it?

Comment: yes try it. on your control or directly on the textbox if it is an asp:textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supose you set the input's value in code behind right?

Anyways, you might try using **`document.querySelector`**, and it seems that your logical operator is wrong, you are using **`|`** instead of **`||`**.

```
function CheckContactName() {
    let name = document.querySelector(
        '#ContentPlaceHolder1_ContactList_con_fullname'
    );

    if ((name.value == '') || (name.value == null) || (name == undefined)) {
        return false;
    }

    UploadContact();

    return true;
}
```

Comment: No I do not set value in code behind and "|" will just try first expression first if it is false it will not care for the other one. I will look into querySelector.

Comment: Does that work in Javascript tho? As far as I know in C# it does but never tested it on Javascript.

Comment: Still, value is undefined either way

Answer (score 1):

Changed **name** to **cname**.

It seems that when you use control on a page that already contains some JavaScript function and that function declares variable with the same name as the one in usercontrol - this happends.

Comment: But how to avoid it?